# Update different oracle database from different oracle database

Tags: oracle

I want to update a CLOB column in **B** Oracle 11g database using a CLOB column in **A** Oracle 11g database located in a different server.

What are the different ways to do that? and which is the best and easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B:

```
create database link dblink_to_a connect to myuser identified by mypassword using 'tns_a';

merge into destination_table d using source_table@dblink_to_a s on (d.id = s.id) when matched then update set d.myclob = s.myclob;
commit;
```